# Why does type(of: object) == ClassName.self return a wrong result?

Tags: swift, polymorphism, instanceof, rtti, typeof

I have the following code:

```
class Mode { ... }
class TimelapseMode: Mode { ... }
var mode: Mode! = TimelapseMode()
```

When I check `type(of: mode) == TimelapseMode.self` it returns false, which is obviously wrong. I confirmed by setting a breakpoint and printing mode, it is indeed `TimelapseMode`.

However `type(of: mode) === TimelapseMode.self` and `mode is TimelapseMode` both return true.

Is it that the == operator isn't implemented correctly by the metatype class?

Should I go through my entire codebase replacing such uses of == with ===?

Comment: For me `type(of: mode) == TimelapseMode.self` returns true as well

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem either.

Comment: Don't you mean that `type(of: mode) == Mode.self` returns false ?

Comment: The variable was an implicitly unwrapped optional. I updated the question with that info. Sorry for forgetting it earlier. It's still the case that == returns false and === returns true. I don't understand why this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

**Type.self** 
The meta type of a type can be found by calling .self on a type. The returned type can either be a Class meta-type, a Struct meta-type or a Protocol meta-type.

```
class Mode {

}


class TimeslapeMode: Mode {

}

var mode: Mode = Mode()

print(type(of: mode))
print(TimeslapeMode.self)

print(type(of: mode) === TimeslapeMode.self)
print(type(of: mode) == TimeslapeMode.self)

print(type(of: mode))
print(type(of: TimeslapeMode.self))

Output -
Mode
TimeslapeMode
false
false
Mode
TimeslapeMode.Type
```

[image]

Comment: The variable was an implicitly unwrapped optional. I updated the question with that info. Sorry for forgetting it earlier. It's still the case that == returns false and === returns true. I don't understand why this is the case.

Comment: I write a code of two cases == or === both return true.

Comment: Change the type of mode to Mode! and run your code again

Comment: Ofcourse it return false beacause mode type is Mode and TimeslapMode.self is return TimeslapMode class type.

Comment: No, the static type of mode is Mode! but the dynamic type is TimelapseMode. Read my updated question again. Why do === and is return true but == return false?

Comment: Because mode is type Mode class and TimeslapeMode is type of TimeslapeMode so both is not equal, Can you please check the answer i updated with output.

Comment: You didn't understand my point. In your code, please change "var mode: Mode" to "var mode: Mode!" and run it again, and you'll be able to see what I'm pointing out.